# Laravel can't read a vue file

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel cannot find the Vue instance that is created in app.js.

this is vue file Follow.vue

```
<template> 
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4">Follow me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('follow', require('./components/Follow.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

and part of the blade page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
   <div id="app">
               <follow></follow>
   </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

home page in

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

and I still don't see the button

and when I hit inspect it goes this message:

```
app.js?6d40:5 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function
    at eval (app.js?6d40:5)
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace `window.Vue = require('vue');` with `import Vue from 'vue';`?

Comment: What version of Vue have you installed in your `package.json`?

Comment: run `npm install && npm run dev`

Comment: thank you @tao, it is fixed now and working... thank you all